# how do I programmatically get GDI and User Object count in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a program thats starting to reach the 10,000 User Object limit.
When I force it to go over the limit the program crashes.
I could have my users change the registry entry but that is a awkward thing to ask a customer and many are not given access to the registry.

I can see the value in Task manager but I would like to get the value in my application.
Is there any way to get those values programmatically?

OK I am now ready for all the comments about how only a badly written program needs that many objects ;>)

Comment: here it comes.....  No seriously, I'm curious to know what your app does that pushes up against that limit; please do enlighten us all!

Comment: It is a Command and Control and Performance monitor for a mainframe class computer (HP NonStop or Tandem).  It has over 125 screens of information (process,cpu,disks,files,console logs etc).  These screens, once they have been displayed by the user, start auto-updating so when the user returns to the screen the values are up to date.  So I am not able to destroy objects.  I have over 600,000 lines of code so far and I continue to add new features.

Comment: why don't you release the window handle of each form when it is not showing by calling DestroyHandle?

Comment: Would the items keep updating so when the user returns to the page the values would be correct.  and will I need the handles later?

Comment: Are you storing your data in windows controls like, say, list boxes, list views etc., or are you storing your data in specialised data structures and then using the controls to view the data? If the former then you may have problems, but if the latter then you should be in the clear. It seems to me though that if your app was well factored then you shouldn't need anything like 10,000 objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [`GetGuiResources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683192(VS.85).aspx). Pass GetCurrentProcess() as parameter